# Spark SQL, Is it possible to write a JdbcDialect that could parse JAVA_OBJECT type and convert it into StructType?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a `JdbcDialect` for Presto that would be able to parse Presto's `ARRAY` and `ROW` types.

In the dialect that I wrote, I was able to transform Presto's `ARRAY` to Spark's `ArrayType`, but it seems that a `StructType` is not supported at all in the [`JdbcUtils.makeGetter`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L381), so I cannot transform `ROW` into it.

Is it at all supported? Am I missing something?